# How to load my navbar from another HTML file without using a server?

Tags: html, css

I just can't get any solution to work! I have tried everything, only object/iframe works, but they are ugly, as my navbar has a scrollbar like it was a page.

I don't want to use server-sided stuff, I just need something for my "offline" website. I have to bring this website on a CD at my school.

My navbar_file.html contains this:

```
<a href="index.html"><div id="button">Acasă</div></a>
   <div class="dropdown" id="button">Prezentare
      <div class="dropdown_content">
         <a href="istoric.html">Scurt istoric</a><br><br>
         <a>Organigramă</a><br><br>
         <a>Ofertă educaţională</a><br><br>
         <a>Cadre didactice</a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="dropdown" id="button">Nivel de învăţământ
       <div class="dropdown_content">
           <a>Învăţământ primar</a><br><br>
           <a>Învăţământ gimnazial</a><br><br>
           <a>Învăţământ liceal</a>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="dropdown" id="button">Admitere și înscriere
       <div class="dropdown_content">
            <a>Clasa pregătitoare</a><br><br>
            <a>Admitere liceu</a>
       </div>
   </div>
    <div class="dropdown" id="button">Examene naționale
         <div class="dropdown_content">
              <a>Evaluarea națională</a><br><br>
              <a>Bacalaureat</a>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" id="button">Activităţi şi proiecte
         <div class="dropdown_content">
              <a>Activităţi extracurriculare</a><br><br>
              <a>Olimpiade și concursuri</a><br><br>
              <a>Programe educaţionale</a><br><br>
              <a>Programe culturale</a><br><br>
              <a>Programe umanitare</a>
          </div>
    </div>
    <a href="https://sites.google.com/site/asavlaicu/home"><div id="button">Asociaţia Sportivă</div></a>
    <a href="contact.html"><div id="button">Contact</div></a>
```

Is there anything wrong with this? Do I need to add  tags?

Then in my index.html page I have a div with the id="navbar". I don't know how to make it work from here. I tried jQuery, doesn't work, iframe/objects are pretty ugly. Also I need to keep my stylesheet.css format. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#navbar").load("navbar_file.html");
});` can you try this, add this to your index page

Comment: do i need to include jquery or what? or is this js?

Comment: yes, add jquery.

Comment: doesn't work. the navbar is empty... it has the black background, width, height that i've set in css, but the content isn't there. i don't know what is wrong honestly. is this server-sided?

Comment: no, do you have exisiting js for your navbar?

Comment: i don't. i have included jquery, i have added the code in <head>, i have created my navbar_file.html with a simple text "hello" in it, nothing loads.  I don't know what is wrong. I have checked a lot of times and there's no mistake.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169632/discussion-between-mark-gerryl-mirandilla-and-hydravink).

Comment: Did you add <script>...</script> tags around the above?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the only thing that worked for me is loading a .js file:

```
<script src="b.js"></script>
```

And then, in this file, put the external nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

Directly before your closing body tag (ie `</body>`), Include this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#navbar").load("navbar_file.html"); 
    });
</script>
```

Ensure you have this where you want your navbar to sit:

```
<div id="navbar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use server side stuff, then jquery load/GET is what you need

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#header').load('header.html');
        $('#menu').load('nav.html');
        $('#body').load('body.html');
        $('#footer').load('footer.html');
    });
</script>
```